# JavaEE API for WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, dependencies, weblogic

There are different server specific JavaEE API implementations like: glassfish-javaee or jboss-javaee.
They are distributed as a separate .jar file and could be attached to some project using Maven dependencies.
Is there something like this desinged specifically for WebLogic AS?
I expected weblogic.jar file contains requered artifacts, but it doesn't look like this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use the javaee-api dependency, not something that is server specific.  For the things that are server-specific (not core EE API) then you could include weblogic.jar or use the utilities with WebLogic to create the WLFullClient.jar file.

Java EE 5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Java EE 6:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

More info here: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/591/

UPDATE:
I would suggest reading this information about client JAR files: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/basics.html

You may also be interested in the WebLogic Maven Plugin.  Here is a YouTube video describing how to use it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcwcGtz0dyc

...and the example project with Maven here: https://www.samplecode.oracle.com/sf/projects/oracle-parcel-svc/

Comment: thank you for your reply. I used javaee-api dependency, but I included some EjbUnit tests which require not api, but some specific javaee implementation. So now I'm in a doubt, how to handle it. I added glassfish-javaee.jar and it works ok, but I guess it's better to find some WebLogic specific solution since I use it as an application server.